# secrets manager.list Permission denied despite granting access to the secretmanager.viewer role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I added the rule
`resource.name.extract("projects/${project_id}/secrets/secrets_{suffix}") != '' && resource.name.extract("_endpoint{suffix}") == ''`
to the condition editor, and my test service account for access testing does not have permission to list secrets, but it does for gcloud secrets version list

my role is to provide access to secrets that start with secrets_ and do not contain the word "endpoint" in the secret name, unfortunately I cannot use contain and match. I tried using startsWith but the same problem occurs

Comment: Do you need to provide the `$` sign before your variables? Eg `.extract("_endpoint${suffix}")`. It looks like you have for the `${project_id}` but not for suffix.